# While loop function

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I would like to set up a while loop function or any other possibilities in order to use once str(input()) and not to repeat the operation 10 times.

```
# Name of the player for the game
colonne= ['player_name']
df = []
for player in colonne:
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'Numéro': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
             player: [
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
                 str(input()),
            ],
        }
    ).set_index('Numéro')
    df.append(df_1)
df = pd.concat(df, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Replace the list with `[str(input()) for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: You can also create 'Numero' list with `list(range(1,11))`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the inputs with loop:

```
# Name of the player for the game
colonne= ['player_name']
df = []
for player in colonne:
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'Numéro': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
             player: [str(input()) for _ in range(10)],
        }
    ).set_index('Numéro')
    df.append(df_1)
df = pd.concat(df, axis=1)
print(df)
```

I would reccomend renaming `Numéro` as well, using diacritics might lead to problems in different systems in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the list by,

```
for i in range(0,10):
    player.append(str(input()))
```